# Rules of the Kurukshetra war in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, kurukshetra, war

Anyone knows all the rules of the main Kurukshetra war of Mahabharata?

And who had broken any particular rule?

I want to know all rules and the names of character that broke any particular rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Mahabharata epic, which describes the Kurukshetra war, the two sides agree on the following rules:

- Fighting must begin no earlier than sunrise and should end by exact sunset. (Broken on the 14th day, after Jayadratha was slain).
- Multiple warriors must not attack a single warrior. (Broken several times, most notably in the 13th day, when Abhimanyu was slain).
- Two warriors may duel, or engage in prolonged personal combat, only if they carry the same weapons and they are on the same mount (no mount, a horse, an elephant, or a chariot). (Broken several times).
- No warrior may kill or injure a warrior who has surrendered. (Violated when Satyaki slew an unarmed Burishravas).
- One who surrenders becomes a prisoner of war and will then be subject to the protections of a prisoner of war. (There were no prisoners of war taken, in the Kurukshetra War).
- No warrior may kill or injure an unarmed warrior. (Arjuna slew Karna when the latter was helpless).
- No warrior may kill or injure an unconscious warrior. (Broken when Abhimanyu was slain).
- No warrior may kill or injure a person or animal not taking part in the war. (Broken several times when warriors slew horses of their enemies).
- No warrior may kill or injure a warrior whose back is turned away. (Shakuni broke that rule).
- No warrior may strike an animal not considered a direct threat.
- The rules specific to each weapon must be followed. For example, it is prohibited to strike below the waist in mace warfare.
- Warriors must not engage in any 'unfair' warfare whatsoever.
- The lives of women, prisoners of war, and farmers are sacred.
- Land should not be pillaged.

#### References:

- [Dharma-yuddha in the Mahabharata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma-yuddha#Dharma-yuddha_in_the_Mahabharata)
- [Strict Rules of Battle Followed in Mahabharata](http://daily.bhaskar.com/news/JM-know-the-strict-rules-of-battle-followed-in-mahabharata-4392368-PHO.html)
- [Mahabharata Battle - Rules of War](https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/mahabharata-battle-rules-of-war/)
- [Kurukshetra War - Interesting Facts](http://kurukshetralive.com/kurukshetra-war-interesting-facts/)

Comment: OK thanks!  But it's better to cite the actual Mahabharata rather than Wikipedia.  The rules of engagement are given in the first chapter of the Bhishma Parva of the Mahabharata: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06001.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I am searching answer from 6 month, I posted whatever I found. I am getting what you are trying to say. I will take care now. and please don't down vote like this way, if you thing information is wrong then you can down vote.

Comment: I'm not planning on downvoting your answer, I'm just suggesting you improve your answer using that Bhishma Parva chapter I linked to.

Comment: @CapDroid felt like sharing this with you. http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/361/voting-to-have-keshav-srinivasan-take-a-sabbatical-as-a-moderator

Comment: You should cite sources.